# Query Problem in Clustom Plugin

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to do some from a custom plugin in tables of WP-ERP plugin. I am using the following code:

```
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->show_errors( true );
  $table_name= $wpdb->prefix.'erp_acct_products';
  $wpdb->print_error();
  $DBPresults= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name FROM $table_name WHERE id=1");
  $wpdb->print_error();
  echo "<p>User count is {$DBPresults}</p>";
  $wpdb->print_error();
  ?>
```

and it load this errors:

```
WordPress database error: []
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'pm_migration_start_2_3' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: []
SELECT name FROM wp_erp_acct_products WHERE id=1

User count is Array

WordPress database error: []
```

Any idea??

```
SELECT name FROM wp_erp_acct_products WHERE id=1
```

Comment: The first error, with `pm_migration_start_2_3` seems to be completely unrelated to your code. What is the structure of the `wp_erp_acct_products` table?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bilMxfF

Comment: Is there even an error? After formatting the messages you'd included in the question there doesn't appear to be any errors. You appear to be just using `$DBPresults` incorrectly. Based on your query it's an array of names, but you're trying to print a single value. If you want the number of results you need to use `count( $DBPresults )`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SQL succeeded to me. So I guess your problem is that you're getting an array of results (which is probably an array of arrays: rows, then columns per row) when you were expecting a single scalar value.

Try using [get_var()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/) to get a single value from the database:

```
$DBPresults = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT name FROM $table_name WHERE id=1" );
```